# Adding Faker data to Laravel Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, faker

I am creating this application in Laravel.
I have 3 tables, Employees, Departments and Salaries
The Employees table has columns id, name, dept_name,gender, etc.. 
The Departments has dept_name, emp_id
and Salaries has monthlySalaries, emp_id, dept_name

All the above tables were created by these respective models.

The issue I am facing is that when I run the DatabaseSeeder, values do get entered into the DB, but they are not consistent, eg. Employee table with id = 1 and Dept_name = Production, while in Department table emp_id = 1 and Dept_name = Tech Support.
And this problem flows into the salaries table as well.

I know, I am doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what.
I've tried creating a PK on id(employee table) referencing emp_id(salaries) but no luck. 
I have even tried updating the DB seeders script below, but that would not create the salary entries, and in some cases even leave the emp_id(departments) blank.

Any help/pointers to what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.
Thank you for taking out the time to read this :)

**Employee Model:**

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('dept_name');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->timestamp('date_of_joining');
            $table->dateTime('date_of_birth');
            $table->timestamps();
}
```

**Department Model:**

```
 Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('dept_name');
        $table->unsignedInteger('employee_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Salary Model:**

```
        Schema::create('salaries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('monthlySalary');
            $table->unsignedInteger('employee_id');
            $table->string('dept_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Database Seeder**

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call([UsersTableSeeder::class]);
        //creates employees & Departments
        factory(App\Employee::class, 25)->create()->each(function ($employee) {
            $department = factory(App\Department::class)->make();
            $employee->department()->save($department);

            $salary = factory(App\Salary::class)->make();
            $employee->salary()->save($salary);
        });
    }
```

App\Employee

```
public function department()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Department::class);
    }

    public function Salary()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Salary::class);
    }
```

**App\Department**

```
public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
    }
    public function salaries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class);
    }
```

**App\Salary**

```
public function employeeSalary()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
    }
```

Comment: "Employee table with id = 1 and Dept_name = Production, while in Department table emp_id = 1 and Dept_name = Tech Support" should the dept_names be the same or?

Comment: The names should be the same. Essentially, one employee can only have one department and one salary. That is what i am trying to achieve here

Comment: but the factories will fake the data?

Comment: I agree, the faker will fake the data, but what's happening now is that if in my employees table there is a row where the id is 1, and dept_name is Production, the departments table shows emp_id as 1 but dept_name as tech support. Shouldn't it show production in that case, even if it is faking the data. I'm just trying to establish a relation between the different tables, because i havs several SQL queries which run and show different data than whah the MySQL terminal shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel code that you've written looks correct and it looks like it's doing exactly what it should be doing - I think the issue is mainly due to your database scheme.

Ideally, you should step back and consider how your database scheme models the objects you're working with. For example, the following relationships are possible in the scheme you have now:

- an `Employee` has zero or more `Departments`
- an `Employee` has zero or more `Salaries`

And some of the data is duplicated (I think<sup>1</sup>) across tables:

- an `Employee` has a `dept_name` and is also associated with zero or more `Departments`, each of which may have a different `dept_name`

I think what you're really going for is:

- an `Employee` belongs to exactly one `Department`
- an `Employee` has exactly one `Salary`

These kinds of issue can be avoided by structuring your tables like this:

```
employees               departments            salaries
---------               -----------            --------
id                      id                     id
department_id           name                   monthly_salary
salary_id
name
gender
...other columns...
```

Each employee has exactly one `department_id` which refers to a row in the `departments` table (a one-to-many relationship between employees & departments).
Each employee has exactly one `salary_id` which refers to a row in the `salaries` table (a one-to-many relationship between employees & salaries).

If you structure your data this way, an employee's department name comes from the `departments` table (and **only** from that table). There will be no issues with department name mismatches because there is only one source for that information.

The term for this approach to data modelling in relational database is **database normalization**. There are many, many resources out there on the web which can guide you on better ways to structure your data.

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming that an employee can belong to exactly one department. This may not be what you are trying to model.

Comment: Hi, Yes i am trying to do exactly as you are suggesting. One employee has exactly one department and one salary. Initially i had thought of using the I'd(employees) to become the primary key to the emp_id (departments) that didn't work well. I will try out your schema pattern. However how do i ensure that the same values are being inserted across the 3 tables? I mean how do i set up the one to many and many to one relationship especially with primary and foreign key. This is something that I'm completely lost in. Unless I'm inherently doing it in the code without knowing.

Comment: You don't have to assure the tree values are being inserted in this schema, instead of having dept_name everywhere you will access department name through relationships which is correct

Comment: How would I go about setting up the relations in the schema. All this is something I'm new at, and it seems a tad bit difficult. 
Also, I used dept_name instead of dept_id everywhere because during the insertion of data, department names would keep changing, eg. 00 would be HR and then a few entries down, it would be 05 is HR.
So, I thought, that if I had a PK-Foreign Key relation, and some sort of an increment, then this issue may not happen.